# Dynamic change of style

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript

I want to change style of my class based on screen size, like this

```
<p [ngStyle]="{'color': isMobile() ? 'red' : 'blue'}">Lorem Ipsum</p>
```

This piece of code is calling method in my `component.ts`

```
 isMobile() {      
    return window.innerWidth < 640;
 }
```

But from what I see, this function is called only once I click somewhere on the window, not while resizing. How can I make that happen instantly?

Answer (score 1):

You can use media queries like below(Sass):

```
.color-size {
  color: blue;
  @media screen and (max-width: 640px) {
    color: red;
  }
}
```

or pure css:

```
.color-size {
  color: blue;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 640px) {
  .color-size {
    color: red;
  }
}
```

If you want to do it by events in ts:

```
  isMobile: boolean;
  @HostListener('window:resize', ['$event'])
  onResize(event) {
    if (event.target.innerWidth < 640) {
      this.isMobile = true;
    } else {
      this.isMobile = false;
    }
  }
```

and template will be:

```
<p (window:resize)="onResize($event)" [ngStyle]="{ color: isMobile ? 'red' : 'blue' }">Lorem Ipsum</p>
```